# XHTML-Doctype in Websites still valid to use?

Tags: html

im just checking a website and the html starts with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

This is not used today in a small web-project with no special functions. Is this correct? And if its still used, what is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

XHTML 1.0 is outdated ([it is explicitly marked as superseded](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/)) but the specification still exists, so it is technically valid.

We can't usefully speculate on why some site has been written using it.